# Is there a way to make the dot badge in Material-UI bigger?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, web, material-ui

I have a badge component that needs to work as an indicator. I don't need the badge to display any values so I used the dot variant, but it is really small. I assume I could modify it with CSS but is not working for some reason. Any help or tips?

```html
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme)=>({
  dot: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    height: 8,
    minWidth:8,
  }
}));
function NotesBadge({hasNotes}){
  const classes=useStyles();
  return(
    <Badge
      className={{dot: classes.dot}}
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical:'top',
        horizontal:'right',}}
        variant="dot"
        color="primary"
        invisible={!hasNotes}>
    </Badge>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This `className={{dot: classes.dot}}` applies styles to the `dot wrapper` span. To target the actual span, which is creating the `dot`, you can target the `MuiBadge-dot` class.

Updated `makeStyles`

```
dot: {
"& .MuiBadge-dot": {
    height: 20,
    minWidth: 20,
    borderRadius: 10
  }
}
```

Updated Badge component.

```
<Badge
  className={{dot: classes.dot}}
  anchorOrigin={{
  vertical:'top',
  horizontal:'right',}}
  variant="dot"
  color="primary"
  invisible={!hasNotes}>
</Badge>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-1vvk5?file=/demo.js:1758-1891)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `dot` variant to be as big as the `standard` variant, set the `badgeContent` to an empty string:

```
<Badge color="secondary" badgeContent="">
  <MailIcon />
</Badge>
```

But if you want a custom size, you need to override the [dot class name](https://mui.com/api/badge/#:%7E:text=dot-,.MuiBadge-dot,-Class%20name%20applied) like below:

```
import Badge, { badgeClasses } from "@mui/material/Badge";
```

```
<Badge
  color="secondary"
  variant="dot"
  sx={{
    [`& .${badgeClasses.dot}`]: {
      width: size,
      height: size,
      borderRadius: "50%"
    }
  }}
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]